# Get the real extension of a file vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vba

I would like to determine real file extension.

example :

```
   file = "test.fakeExt"
    // but the real extention is .exe // for security reason I wish to avoid using it!
```

How can I do that?

Comment: please post more code for us to help. how do u get the filename? in c#, string[] s= file.split('.'); string ext = s[s.Length-1];

Comment: What do you mean by the 'real extension'? If it is a link it will have a .lnk extension

Comment: You could use the FileInfo class. Handling with strings to get filenames is a bad idea.

Comment: I mean that I have some fake extention, some ppl send me fraud files with (.exe) but they put a fake ext (.txt). So I would like to detecte real extention for security reason! I wish to get MIME type of the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if a file is an exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863683/how-to-find-if-a-file-is-an-exe)

Comment: It might corrupt file (virus infected !) ...

Comment: It won't do anything malicious unless you change the extension yourself and how would you know what to change it to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the extension you could use findmimefromdata.
It looks at the first part of the file to determine what type of file it is.

[FindMimeFromData function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Sample code](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata)

Answer (score 1):

The first two bytes of an .exe file are allways 'MZ'.

So you could read the binary file, and see if the first two bytes are MZ, then you know it's an .exe file...