# How to properly validate file from user and detect extension change?

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public bool IsImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var contentType = file.ContentType.Split("/")(0).ToLower() == "image"

    if (contentType != "image")
    {
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

however if the user rename an `.exe` file to `.jpg`, it will still think it is a valid image file. How to prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if a file is an exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863683/how-to-find-if-a-file-is-an-exe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to check whether it's an image is to load it *as* an image, e.g. using `Image.FromStream`. If that throws an exception, it's not an image (or at least, not a supported image format). I'd trust that more than just using either the extension or the claimed MIME type.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The OP could certainly use the headers as a first pass - but again with the date handling, I'd prefer to use date parsing code than a regex for example, as it's much more likely to get all the rules for leap years right. (Of course I'd prefer to use an API which allowed me to try to parse *without* raising an exception for failure, but that's a slightly different matter.) Basically, a date parser, image loader or whatever is a piece of code designed precisely to judge whether or not the data is valid (and interpret it). Why use something less precise, other than as an initial pass?